# How to make a simple table in ReportLab

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

How can I make simple table in ReportLab? I need to make a simple 2x20 table and put in some data. Can someone point me to an example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest table function:

```
table = Table(data, colWidths=270, rowHeights=79)
```

How many columns & end rows depend from tuple of data. All our table functions looks like:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tables import Table
cm = 2.54

def print_pdf(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.pdf'

    elements = []

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(response, rightMargin=0, leftMargin=6.5 * cm, topMargin=0.3 * cm, bottomMargin=0)

    data=[(1,2),(3,4)]
    table = Table(data, colWidths=270, rowHeights=79)
    elements.append(table)
    doc.build(elements) 
    return response
```

This will make table 2X2, and fill it with numbers 1,2,3,4. Then you can make file document. In my case i made HttpResponse what is pretty the same like file.

Comment: For me it creates the table all fine but the table is filled in sort of in reverse so the table looks Row 1: 3 4
Row 2: 1 2

Answer (score 1):

Just an add on to radtek and Pol's answer:

You can substitute the `response` argument to SimpleDocTemplate() with a buffer object like io.BytesIO() like so:

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.platypus.tables import Table
import io

cm = 2.54
buffer = io.BytesIO()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, rightMargin=0, leftMargin=6.5 * cm, topMargin=0.3 * cm, bottomMargin=0)
... # To be continued below
```

This could be useful in cases when you want to convert the PDF object into bytes and then into byte-string to be sent in JSON format:

```
... # Continuation from above code
buffer.seek(0)
buffer_decoded = io.TextIOWrapper(buffer, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').read()

return JsonResponse({
    "pdf_bytes": buffer_decoded,
})
```

Taken from the doc (https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf):
[image]

```
The required filename can be a string, the name of a file to receive the created PDF document; alternatively it can be an object which has a write method such as aBytesIO or file or socket
```